# How to fix the binding of React Component from Parent to Children

Tags: reactjs, input, react-props

I want to update the value of State in ParentComponent with setState. So I define a `handleChange` and a `handleSubmit` functions, then I pass them to the Children Component Form Input.
I binding this like this and on the Children Component Input, I can't type more than 1 character. The State alway update after every character.
I think my problem with the binding, please help me with this.

I bind to the Children by many ways but it won't work, and on the Children Component Input, I can't type more than 1 character. The State always updates after every character.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    user:{
      ...this.state.user,
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value
      } 
    }) 
}
```

Pass to the Child:

```
<route.component handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} handleChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} {...props} {...this.state} />
```

And the Child Component:

```
const SignInForm = ({handleChange,handleSubmit}) =>(

  <ListGroup>
    <ListGroupItem className="p-3">
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form >
            <Row form>
              <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="feEmailAddress">Email: </label>
                <FormInput
                  onChange = {evt=>handleChange(evt)}
                  id="feEmailAddress"
                  type="email"
                  name ='email'
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col md="6">
                <label htmlFor="fePassword">Password :</label>
                <FormInput
                onChange = {evt=>handleChange(evt)}
                  id="fePassword"
                  type="password"
                  name = "password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Button onClick = {(evt)=>handleSubmit(evt)}>Log In</Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </ListGroupItem>
  </ListGroup>
)
```

I expect to update both value username and password, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the handlers properly but don't pass the value, hence it's not updated after every stroke.

```
   const SignInForm = ({handleChange, handleSubmit, email}) =>(
     ...
   )
```

```
                <FormInput
                  value={email}
                  onChange = {evt=>handleChange(evt)}
                  id="feEmailAddress"
                  type="email"
                  name ='email'
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
```

P.S.: The binding of the handlers should be done in the component's constructor, instead of the render method.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I think I understand your issue, I edited the answer